# Reversing, Restoring, and taking over Active Directory Roles

Tags: active-directory, fsmo

I am out to upgrade our 2003 Windows Server to a 2012 Windows Server.
From what I read I will be using dcpromo to promote a 2012 Server to take over a 2003 servers master roles.
Questions:

1-- Given the AD forest is set as a 2003 forest,  can I switch master roles both forward and back between the 2003 and 2012 server machines as desired?

2--If one server with a master role should fail, can I tell the other server to take over that role?  how?

3--Will a server automatically take over a master role if another server with that master role fail or go offline?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. No.